# How to use the flexbox with html and css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to add heading `H1` and text under the headings and the a `link` when you click the box.

The picture shows an example of what I mean:

[image]

Here is my current code

```
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Heading 1</div>
  <div>Heading 2</div>
  <div>Heading 3</div>  
</div>
```

How can I make the whole box clickable and add the smaller text like shown in the image above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For heading, you can use [h1 element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements), and add another element for the sub text under it. Finally you can wrap both with the anchor tag.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > a {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.flex-container h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <a href="#"><h1>Heading 1</h1><div>Sub text 1</div></a>
  <a href="#"><h1>Heading 2</h1><div>Sub text 2</div></a>
  <a href="#"><h1>Heading 3</h1><div>Sub text 3</div></a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `justify-content` property, we can use `flex` property with default value be `1` which can took the width automatically horizontally evenly without any extra-space in left side. Find the ***working code*** below :

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  color: white;
}

.flex-container a {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #ec4141;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.flex-container h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.flex-container div {
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <a href="#">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <div>Sub text 1 Sub text 1 Sub text 1 Sub text 1 Sub text 1 Sub text 1 Sub text 1</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    <div>Sub text 2 Sub text 2 Sub text 2 Sub text 2 Sub text 2 Sub text 2</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <h1>Heading 3</h1>
    <div>Sub text 3 Sub text 3 Sub text 3</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How can I make the whole box clickable > Put an  tag around it
Smaller text: Add another element and customize it as you wish

I've also added `justify-content: space-around` in flex container for you. End result is the same as the screenshot in your question.

```html
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

  .flex-element {
    display: block;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="flex-container">
  <a class="flex-element" href="#"><div>Heading 1 <p>I am a little text </p></div></a>
 <a class="flex-element" href="#"> <div>Heading 2 <p>I am a little text </p></div></a>
 <a class="flex-element" href="#"> <div>Heading 3 <p>I am a little text </p></div>  </a>
</div>
```